# AWK unix command

Tags: unix, awk

I have been searching and I have some doubts about this awk command.
Any one can help on what does it do?

```
awk -F'\" ' '$2~/^5/' /home/app/log/app_log_20171202.out
```

I think it search's for a string inside the log file, but I don't understand the pattern that it search.

Answer (score 0):

Your awk line does the following :

`awk -F'\" ' '$2~/^5/'`

- `-F'\" '` : set the field delimiter to be `'" '` (double quote with space)
- `$2~/^5/` is a short form for writing `($2~/^5/)1` which is even short for `($2~/^5/){print $0}` and should be read as `if ($2~/^5/) is true then print $0`.
- The regular expression is `$2~/^5/` and states that if the second field with delimiter `"` (see `-F'\"`) starts with a 5 (`/^5/`), then return true.

So in short your command print all lines where the first string encapsulated in quotes starts with a 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess.

Breaking it down. awk -F'\" ' '$2~/^5/' /home/app/log/app_log_20171202.out

awk  the command

-F'\" ' use " and a space as the field separator.

'$2~/^5/' the awk series of patterns and actions to apply to input file

$2 return second item

~  matches the pattern to follow

/^5/  match One character that is 5

/home/app/log/app_log_20171202.out  an input file.

Here are some examples using echo and a pipe instead of an input file.

This returns the line.

```
echo "VM\" 5ID: 12345" | awk -F'\" ' '$2~/^5/' -
VM" 5ID: 12345
```

These return nothing.

```
echo "VM\" 4ID: 12345" | awk -F'\" ' '$2~/^5/' -
echo "VM\"5ID: 12345" | awk -F'\" ' '$2~/^5/' -
```

Comment: You said, "/^5/ match One character that is 5", but that's not accurate, because `^` asserts position at start of the string and `5` matches the character `5` literally, so it only matches `5` at the start of the string and not anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Explained using a few examples and simplified code :

```
$ cat abc
contains 2 " contains 5 " contains 10 " contains 100
$
```

Print the second field

```
$ awk -F'\" ' '{print $2 }' abc
contains 5
```

Print the second field if it contains 5

```
$ awk -F'\" ' '$2 ~ /5/ { print $2 }' abc        
contains 5
```

Print the second field if it starts with 5

```
$ awk -F'\" ' '$2 ~ /^5/ { print $2 }' abc
$
```

Modify the file to begin the second field with number 5

```
$ cat abc
contains 2 " 5 is the first number " contains 10 " contains 100
$ awk -F'\" ' '$2 ~ /^5/ { print $2 }' abc
5 is the first number 
$
```

Print entire line if the second field begins with number 5

```
$ awk -F'\" ' '$2 ~ /^5/ { print }' abc   
contains 2 " 5 is the first number " contains 10 " contains 100
$
```

Same as above

```
$ awk -F'\" ' '$2 ~ /^5/' abc          
contains 2 " 5 is the first number " contains 10 " contains 100
$
```